# Phpmyadmin v4.1.14 shows permission denied in windows 7?

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, localhost, wamp, wampserver

I am using windows 7 ultimate OS, in this i have installed the wamp server. But it not loading phpmyadmin page, it shows you don't have permission to access this folder. I have tried many ways but i don't know why it is not working. I think my version problem or not. I am using phpmyadmin V4.1.14 and appache 2.4.9. Please help me, below i have given the conf file code.

```
Alias /phpmyadmin "E:/wamp/apps/phpmyadmin4.1.14/"

# to give access to phpmyadmin from outside 
# replace the lines
#
# Require local
#
# by
#
# Require all granted
#

<Directory "E:/wamp/apps/phpmyadmin4.1.14/">
   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
   AllowOverride all
  <IfDefine APACHE24>
    Require local
  </IfDefine>
  <IfDefine !APACHE24>
     Order Deny,Allow
      Deny from all
      Allow from 127.0.0.1 ::1
    </IfDefine>
  php_admin_value upload_max_filesize 128M
  php_admin_value post_max_size 128M
  php_admin_value max_execution_time 360
  php_admin_value max_input_time 360
</Directory>
```

This is my hosts file,

```
# Copyright (c) 1993-2009 Microsoft Corp.
#
# This is a sample HOSTS file used by Microsoft TCP/IP for Windows.
#
# This file contains the mappings of IP addresses to host names. Each
# entry should be kept on an individual line. The IP address should
# be placed in the first column followed by the corresponding host name.
# The IP address and the host name should be separated by at least one
# space.
#
# Additionally, comments (such as these) may be inserted on individual
# lines or following the machine name denoted by a '#' symbol.
#
# For example:
#
#      102.54.94.97     rhino.acme.com          # source server
#       38.25.63.10     x.acme.com              # x client host

# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
#   127.0.0.1       localhost
#   ::1             localhost

127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.0.1       localhost
```

As per your comment i have added like this.

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
::1       localhost
```

But not working , same error showing.

Comment: Better ask this on http://serverfault.com/.

Comment: Show us your HOSTS file `c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts`

Comment: i have added hosts file above, check it

Comment: Try removing all the `127.0.0.1 localhost` duplicates leaving just one. Then add this one as well `::1  localhost` then try phpMyAdmin again.

Comment: I have added like this 
127.0.0.1       localhost 
::1       localhost
 but it also not working.